# How to influence the Postgres Query Analyzer when dealing with text search and geospatial data

Tags: postgresql, postgis, query-analyzer

I have a quite serious performance issue with the following statement that i can't fix myself.

**Given Situation**

- I have a postgres 8.4 Database with Postgis 1.4 installed
- I have a geospatial table with ~9 Million entries. This table has a (postgis) geometry column and a tsvector column
- I have a GIST Index on the geometry and a VNAME Index on the vname column
- Table is `ANALYZE`'d

I want to excecute a `to_tsquery`text search within a subset of these geometries that should give me all affecteded ids back.

The area to search in will limit the 9 Million datasets to approximately 100.000 and the resultset of the `ts_query` inside this area will most likely give an output of 0..1000 Entries.

**Problem**

The query analyzer decides that he wants to do an Bitmap Index Scan on the vname first, and then aggreates and puts a filter on the geometry (and other conditions I have in this statement)

Query Analyzer output:

```
Aggregate  (cost=12.35..12.62 rows=1 width=510) (actual time=5.616..5.616 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Bitmap Heap Scan on mxgeom g  (cost=8.33..12.35 rows=1 width=510) (actual time=5.567..5.567 rows=0 loops=1)
     Recheck Cond: (vname @@ '''hemer'' & ''hauptstrasse'':*'::tsquery)
     Filter: (active AND (geom && '0107000020E6100000010000000103000000010000000B0000002AFFFF5FD15B1E404AE254774BA8494096FBFF3F4CC11E40F37563BAA9A74940490200206BEC1E40466F209648A949404DF6FF1F53311F400C9623C206B2494024EBFF1F4F711F404C87835954BD4940C00000B0E7CA1E4071551679E0BD4940AD02004038991E40D35CC68418BE49408EF9FF5F297C1E404F8CFFCB5BBB4940A600006015541E40FAE6468054B8494015040060A33E1E4032E568902DAE49402AFFFF5FD15B1E404AE254774BA84940'::geometry) AND (mandator_id = ANY ('{257,1}'::bigint[])))
     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gis_vname_idx  (cost=0.00..8.33 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=5.566..5.566 rows=0 loops=1)
           Index Cond: (vname @@ '''hemer'' & ''hauptstrasse'':*'::tsquery)
```

which causes a LOT of I/O - AFAIK It would be smarter to limit the geometry first, and do the vname search after.

**Attempted Solutions**

To achieve the desired behaviour i tried to

1. I Put the geom @@ `AREA` into a subselect  -> Did not change the execution plan
2. I created a temporary view with the desired area subset -> Did not change the execution plan
3. I created a temporary table of the desired area -> Takes 4~6 seconds to create, so that made it even worse.

Btw, sorry for not posting the actual query: I think my boss would really be mad at me if I did, also I'm looking more for theoretical pointers for someone to fix my actual query. Please ask if you need further clarification

---

**EDIT**

Richard had a very good point: You can achieve the desired behaviour of the Query Planner with the `width` statement. The bad thing is that this temporary Table (or CTE) messes up the vname index, thus making the query return nothing in some cases.

I was able to fix this with creating a new vname on-the-fly with `to_tsvector()`, but this is (too) costly - around 300 - 500ms per query.

**My Solution**

I ditched the vname search and went with a simple `LIKE('%query_string%')` (10-20 ms/query), but this is only fast in my given environment. YMMV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been some improvements in statistics handling for tsvector (and I think PostGIS too, but I don't use it). If you've got the time, it might be worth trying again with a 9.1 release and see what that does for you.

However, for this single query you might want to look at the WITH construct.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html

If you put the geometry part as the WITH clause, it will be evaluated first (guaranteed) and then that result-set will filtered by the following SELECT. It might end up slower though, you won't know until you try.

It might be an adjustment to work_mem would help too - you can do this per-session ("SET work_mem = ...") but be careful with setting it too high - concurrent queries can quickly burn through all your RAM.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config-resource.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-RESOURCE-MEMORY

Comment: Thanks Richard! As I stated in my edit the with - contruct did manypulate the query plan as expected, but it came out too slow in the end, and i found a workaround. Unfortunately i'm not able to switch to 9.1 due to other legacy frameworks depending on 8.4 :(